# Speed up clicks in Protractor

Tags: angular, protractor

I'm trying to test a ripple effect on a button but when running the tests a click takes about 1 second to perform and by then the ripple effect has already disappeared.

Code:

```
let button =  element(by.css('#primary-button'));

button.click();
expect(element.all(by.css('#primary-button .ripple-effect')).count()).toBe(1);
```

I've also tried mouse down/up but facing the same issue.

This example takes about 10 seconds to perform:

```
let button =  element(by.css('#primary-button'));

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    button.click();
}

expect(element.all(by.css('#primary-button .ripple-effect')).count()).toBe(10);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to speed up AngularJS protractor tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660758/is-there-a-way-to-speed-up-angularjs-protractor-tests)

Comment: Are you sure this delay isn't caused by the protractor/angular synchronization?  click events should be very quick, definitely less than 1 second in my experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest couple tricks:

1) Disable implicit waits for this test `browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0)` They are applied before every searching of element, so might introduce a little delay.

2) Disable Angular synchronization for this test: `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`. This is also applied before every action, but here it just might slow down our clicks.

3) Try with low level api -

```
let button =  element(by.css('#primary-button'))
browser.actions().click(button).perform()
```

this works by coordinates, so might be faster

4) Switch to executing javascript on the page with `browser.executeScript()` - you might click and return true from your script when ripple effect is present, and then just assert for returned true in your test. Is also should be pretty fast, but thats will be synthetic click, not like regular users do clicks.